# Stateless & asynchronous web-server with PHP (and Symfony)

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, asynchronous, stateless

TL;DR: I'm not sure this topic has its place on StackOverflow, but basically it's just a topic of debate and thinking about making PHP apps like we would do with NodeJS for example (stateless request flow, asynchronous calls, etc.)

### The situation

We know NodeJS can be used as both a web-server and web-app.

But for PHP, [the internal web-server is not recommended for production](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php) (so says the documentation).

But, as Symfony full-stack is based on the `Kernel` which handles `Request` objects, it means we *should* be able  to send lots of requests to the same kernel, only if we could "bootstrap" the php web-server (not the app) by creating a kernel before listening to HTTP requests. And our router would only create a Request object and make the kernel handle it.

But for this, a Symfony app has to be **stateless**, for example we need Doctrine to effectively clear its unit of work after a request, or maybe we would need to sort of *isolate* some components based on a request (By identifying a request with its unique PHP class reference id? Or by using other php processes?), and obviously, we would need more asynchronous things in PHP or in the way we use the internal web-server.

### The main questions I sometimes ask myself, and now ask to the community

To clarify this, I have some questions about PHP:

1. Why *exactly* is the internal PHP webserver not recommended for production?
   I mean, if we can configure how the server is run and its "router" file, we should be able to use it like any PHP server, yes or no?
2. How does it behaves internally? Is memory shared between two requests?
   By using the router, it seems obvious to me that variables are not shared, else we could make nodejs-like apps, but it seems PHP is not capable of doing something like this.
3. Is it really possible to make a full-stateless application with Symfony?
   e.g. I send two different requests to the same kernel object, in this case, is there any possibility that the two requests create a conflict in Symfony core components?
4. Actually, the idea of *"Create a kernel -> start server -> on request, make the kernel handle it"* behavior would be awesome, because it would be something quite similar to NodeJS, but actually, the PHP paradigm is not compatible with this because we would need *each request* to be handled asynchronously. But if a kernel and its container is stateless, then, there *should be* a way to do something like that, shouldn't it?

### Some thoughts

I've heard about [React PHP](http://reactphp.org/), [Ratchet PHP](http://socketo.me/) for Websocket integration, [Icicle](https://icicle.io/), [PHP-PM](https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm) but never experienced them, it seems a bit too complex to me for now (I may lack some concepts about asynchronicity in apps, that's why my brain won't understand until I have some more answers :D ).

Is there any way that these libraries could be used as "wrappers" for our kernel request handling?

I mean, let's create this reactphp/icicle/whatever environment setup, create our kernel like we would do in any Symfony app, and run the app as web-server, and when a request is retrieved, we send it asynchrously to our kernel, and as long as the kernel has not sent the response, the client waits for it, even if the response is *also* sent asynchrously (from nested callbacks, etc., like in NodeJS).

This would make any existing Symfony app compatible with this paradigm, as long as the app is stateless, obviously. (if the app config changes based on a request, there's a paradigm issue in the app itself...)

Is it even a possible reality with PHP libraries rather than using PHP internal web-server in another way?

#### Why ask these questions?

Actually, it would be kind of a revolution if PHP could implement *real* asynchronous stuff internally, like Javascript has, but this would also has a big impact on performances in PHP, because of persistent data in our web-server, less bootstraping (require autoloader, instantiate kernel, get heavy things from cached files, resolve routing, etc.).

In my thoughts, only the `$kernel->handleRaw($request);` would consume CPU, the whole rest (container, parameters, services, etc.) would be already in the memory, or, for the case of services, "awaiting to be instantiated". Then, performance boost, I think.

And it may troll a bit the people who still think PHP is a very bad and slow language to use :D

#### For readers and responders ;)

If a core PHP contributor reads me, is there any way that internally PHP could be more asynchronous even with a specific new internal API based on functions or classes?

I'm not a pro of all of these concepts, and I hope really good experts are going to read this and answer me!

It could be a great advance in the PHP world if all of this was possible *in any way*.

Comment: The built in server is single threaded. php is stateless, it is largely because of this that php frameworks tend to be slow - every request the entire framework needs to be loaded into memory, only to be discarded at the end of the request.

Comment: While it's probably not impossible to make PHP behave more like node, the question is why you would want to. Arguably one of PHP's strengths is its simplicity, it simply delegates isolation/async concerns to the web server, and each individual thread is isolated and standalone by its very nature. Javascript/node has had a very different execution model from the beginning; that does not mean that all other languages now need to emulate it. IMO: If you have a different nail, try using a different hammer.

Comment: Have a look at Andrew Carter's talk: "Don't kill the chef" https://andrewcarteruk.github.io/slides/breaking-boundaries-with-fastcgi/

Comment: I understand what you find appealing with `node.js`, it's the simplicity. However, `nginx` + `php-fpm` provide the same, if not even more appealing stack (minus web sockets). PHP's internal web server is made for testing purposes so you don't have to deal with apache/nginx if you want to check something quickly. There are many reasons why it's not suitable for production, one being that it's not an application that deals well with concurrency, and it's not configurable as `nginx` is.

Comment: Another note - why would php implement anything asynchronously? There's no need for that. In `nginx` + `php-fpm` stack, `nginx` plays the role of reactor, while `php-fpm` plays the role of the worker which responds to a task given to it by `nginx`. `nginx` takes care of callback for every http request and plays the async part. It even uses the exact same mechanism as `node.js` does (event loop), except nginx's worker / callback isn't built-in as with node. That lets you write worker tasks in PHP, using synchronous code, completely simplifying the whole process.

Comment: @mjh you're right about nginx, that's why an nginx+php-fpm stack may be more performant than apache+mod_php, but in this case, you cannot "bootstrap" a whole heavy framework in nginx itself, and you cannot store *everything* in an apcu/memcache/redis memory system because you would have to handle data corruption or memory leaks. And what I find appealing in node.js is not the simplicity, actually (it's not simpler than PHP IMO, but a bit more complex because of async), but more the fact that you can do async things *natively*

Comment: @deceze as said, the answer to the "why would you" is that PHP community has grown in a way that there are few frameworks that get on top of the enterprise usage today (Symfony is on top of it, and after comes Laravel and Zend), and they (especially Symfony) want to bring a "best practice policy" to make developers code in a much better way, respect paradigms and design patterns, in order to make application less decoupled, more performant and maintainable.

Comment: @deceze to continue my comment, in node.js, there are lots of new framework each year, and nobody seem to conduct a consensus about "best practices" (even http://jstherightway.org/ is not completely objective because it just sends some links and is in no way provided by a consortium of core/experienced developers of the platform itself)

Comment: Well, PHP has been around since forever, and things have very much settled down. Javascript/node is still very young and everything is up in the air; it has *not* settled down yet. It will eventually. Making PHP more asynchronous doesn't solve that problem at all, since likely all the current frameworks won't work well in the new async world. You'd need to rewrite them all over again from scratch too.

Comment: About 10 years ago PHP was in the same situation, with some hot new framework popping up and dying on the vine every few weeks too.

Comment: @AlexRockAncelet I'm not sure what memory leaks you're referring to. Since `php-fpm` child processes restart themselves (kill + boot a new one) after certain amount of requests served, memory leaks are taken care of. Even if the process dies, everything is still going to be fine since web server will be able to respond that something went wrong. I really can't see what can async approach do for your application exactly, your I/O is mostly going to be related to "talking" to the database, and that's also taken care of for you so you don't have to deal with writing async code.

Answer (score 4):

> Why exactly is the internal PHP webserver not recommended for
>   production? I mean, if we can configure how the server is run and its
>   "router" file, we should be able to use it like any PHP server, yes or
>   no?

Because it's not written to behave well under load, and there are no configuration options that let you handle HTTP request processing *before* it reaches PHP.

Basically, it lacks features if you compare it to `nginx`. It would be equal to comparing a skateboard to a Lamborghini.

It can get you from `A` to `B` but.. you get the gist.

> How does it behaves internally? Is memory shared between two requests?
>   By using the router, it seems obvious to me that variables are not
>   shared, else we could make nodejs-like apps, but it seems PHP is not
>   capable of doing something like this.

Documentation states it's singlethreaded, so it appears that it would behave the same as if you wrote `while(true) { // all your processing here }`.

It's a playtoy designed to quickly check a few things if you can't be bothered to set up a proper web server before trying out your code.

> Is it really possible to make a full-stateless application with
>   Symfony? e.g. I send two different requests to the same kernel object,
>   in this case, is there any possibility that the two requests create a
>   conflict in Symfony core components?

Why would it go to the same kernel object? Why not design your app in such a way that it's not relevant *which* object or even processing server gets the request? Why not design for redundancy and high availability from the get go? HTTP = stateless by default. Your task = make it irrelevant what processes the request. It's not difficult to do so, if you avoid coupling with the actual processing server (example: don't store sessions to local filesystem etc.)

> Actually, the idea of "Create a kernel -> start server -> on request,
>   make the kernel handle it" behavior would be awesome, because it would
>   be something quite similar to NodeJS, but actually, the PHP paradigm
>   is not compatible with this because we would need each request to be
>   handled asynchronously. But if a kernel and its container is
>   stateless, then, there should be a way to do something like that,
>   shouldn't it?

Actually, `nginx` + `php-fpm` behave almost identical to `node.js`.

`nginx` uses a reactor to handle all connections on the same thread. Node.js does the exact same thing. What you do is create a closure / callback that is fed into Node's libraries and I/O is handled in a threaded environment. Multithreading is abstracted from you (related to I/O, not CPU). That's why you can experience that `Node.js` blocks when it's asked to do a CPU intensive task.

`nginx` implements the exact same concept, except this callback isn't a closure written in javascript. It's a callback that expects an answer from `php-fpm` during `<timeout>` seconds. Nginx takes care of async for you. What your task is is to write what you want in PHP. Now, if you're reading a huge file, then async code in your PHP would make sense, except it's not really needed.

With `nginx` and sending off requests for processing to a `fastcgi` worker, scaling becomes trivial. For example, let's assume that 1 PHP machine isn't enough to deal with the amount of requests you're dealing with. No problem, add more machines to nginx's pool.

This is taken from nginx docs:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;

    server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

You define a pool of servers and then assign various weights / proxying options related to balancing how requests are handled.

However, the important part is that you can add more servers to cope with availability requirements.

This is the reason why `nginx` + `php-fpm` stack is appealing. Since `nginx` acts as a proxy, it can proxy requests to `node.js` as well, letting you handle web socket related operations in `node.js` (which, in turn, can perform an HTTP request to a PHP endpoint, allowing you to contain your entire app logic in PHP).

I know this answer might not be what you're after, but what I wanted to highlight is the way `node.js` works (conceptually) is identical to what `nginx` does when it comes to handling incoming request. You could make `php` work as node does, but there's no need for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions can be summed up as this:

"Could PHP be more like Node?"

to which the answer is of course "Yes." But that leads us to another question:

"Should PHP be more like Node?"

and now the answer is not that obvious.

Of course in theory PHP could be made more like Node - even to a point to make it exactly the same. Just take the next version of Node and call it PHP 6.0 or something.

I would argue that it would be harmful to both Node and PHP. There is a diversity in the runtime environments for a reason. One of the variations is the concurrency model used in a given environment. Making one like the other would mean less choice for the programmer. And less choice is less freedom of expression.

PHP and Node were created in different times and for different reasons.

PHP was developed in 1995 and the name stood for Personal Home Page. The use case was to add some server-side dynamic features to HTML. We already had SSI and CGI at that point but people wanted to be able to inject right into the HTML - synchronously, as it wouldn't make much sense otherwise - results of database queries and other computations. It isn't a surprise how good it is at this job even today.

Node, on the other hand, was developed in 2009 - almost 15 years later - to create high performance network servers. So it shouldn't surprise us that writing such servers in Node is easy and that they have great performance characteristics. This is why Node was created in the first place. One of the choices it had to make was a 100% non-blocking environment of single-threaded, asynchronous event loops.

Now, single-threading concurrency is conceptually more difficult than multi-threading. But if you want performance for I/O-heavy operations then currently you have no other options. You will not be able to create 10,000 threads but you can easily handle 10,000 connections with Node in a single thread. There is a reason why nginx is single-threaded and why Redis is single threaded. And one common characteristic of nginx and Redis is amazing performance - but both of those were hard to write.

Now, as far as Node and PHP go, those technologies are so far from each other that it's hard to even comprehend how their fusion would look like. It reminds me [the old April Fool's joke about unifying Perl and Python](https://developers.slashdot.org/story/01/03/28/1742237/perl--python--parrot) that so many people believed in.

PHP has its strengths and Node has it strengths. And just like it would be hard to imagine Node with blocking-I/O, it would be equally hard to imagine PHP with non-blocking I/O.

To summarize: it could be possible to make PHP like Node, but I wouldn't expect it to happen any time soon - if ever.

Comment: I completely understand your point of view, actually I'm not making a debate over PHP vs Node, because I already agreed with what you say befor you even said it :) I'm more talking about PHP future. PHP7 has improved PHP *a lot* and we could expect PHP8 to improve it *a lot more*, for example by implementing asynchronous stuff internally. The goal is not to "replace" or "be exactly like" node.

Comment: In fact, I'm saying this because I started node last year and I found that there is a major issue in the NodeJS world: each year, lots of new frameworks appear. There is not yet "community standards" followed by most developers, and in PHP we have PHP-FIG with the PSRs, and the language is much more friendly to implement known design patterns, whereas Javascript is not, because of the paradigm difference. This makes modern PHP apps more robust in terms of consistency and maintainability, as opposed to JS where it's "too flexible you can do lot of shit", too often unfortunately

Comment: Have you actually worked on something where php 7 was too slow, and coildnt be fixed with a larger server? If yes then take a look at asp.net core with c# - ticks all the points from your second comment above (design patterns, stability, only 1 major framework, which is part of the core)

Comment: @AlexRockAncelet "there is a major issue in the NodeJS world: each year, lots of new frameworks appear." I never understood why people think it's a problem. It's like saying "there is a major issue in capitalism: each year, lots of new companies appear." Actually competition is a major strength of Node - and capitalism. But if you don't like it - just pretend than no new frameworks appear - problem solved. Seriously, if you like Express then why do you have a problem that someone else uses Hapi? Do you seriously think that having a choice is a bad thing?

Comment: @rsp What I think is a problem with lots of new frameworks, is that a young framework cannot be as robust as a framework that is older and that has way more contributions in terms of features, bug fixes and security. We cannot compare capitalism and Node frameworks, because they don't belong to the same universe in terms of engagement and celebrity. A brand new node framework may completely forget to secure itself against some known HTTP issues or things that can break some applications, or some security flaws in the language itself that are not fixable in some environment that cant be updated

Comment: @AlexRockAncelet Of course young frameworks can completely forget to secure itself, just like young companies - but my point is that you don't have to use young frameworks. What I'm saying is that you are free to use the mature, stable frameworks like Express or Hapi and the existence of other young frameworks doesn't mean that the old frameworks stop working or anything like that. With Node you have other options but those options are not mandatory but, well, optional. I don't see a problem of having more options, seriously. Is it a problem that you have a choice?